# Image with 1px srcset wrapped in div occupies height

Tags: css, image

Anybody knows why div having inside image with srcset 1x1px occupies height? In chrome it is 24px, firefox 18px. How to remove them? Thank you.

```
<div class="respwrap">
<img class="" src="/image.jpg" srcset="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" alt="">
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/do7rjcvs/

Comment: What do you want it to look like? A 1x1 div? Div going all the way across? Something else?

Comment: @abney317 Well, 1px across or 1x1px I would assume. Is this correct behavior then?

Comment: You could use `display:inline` on the div to change it, or just set the width and height you want. But yeah, it'll take the default line-height of the browser unless otherwise specified if there is anything inside the div.

Comment: It's based off of the default font size. Set the font-size to zero and the div collapses.